# cp: cannot stat error for .oh-my-zsh but unable to clone git repo in the same directory

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have installed zsh shell and then I tried following for installing **oh my zsh** in Windows 10 as per this

*$git clone git://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git ~/.oh-my-zsh*
worked but then the next command failed

*$cp ~/.oh-my-zsh/templates/zshrc.zsh-template ~/.zshrc*

cp: *cannot stat* '/cygdrive/c/Users/tom.hanks/.oh-my-zsh/templates/zshrc.zsh-template': No such file or directory

I have Windows 10 and cygwin installed.
what am I missing here ?

Comment: What does the `.oh-my-zsh` directory contain? How did you determine that the git clone worked?

Comment: If I try again with git clone
git://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git ~/.oh-my-zsh

I get following error 
fatal: destination path '/cygdrive/c/Users/tom.hanks/.oh-my-zsh' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Comment: You can use the `ls` command to see which files the directory contains, e.g. `ls ~/.oh-my-zsh`

Comment: @hungry4code : So, where did your `zshrc.zsh-template` actually end up then?